# How to program MCU to work with NRF24L01 module in Bascom language?

Tags: avr, nrf24l01, bascom

I want to connect several devices together with this RF module. But it's hard for me to understand the Bascom program. Could you please tell what the main idea is or explain in general for me?

Do you know any reference or tutorial video that can help me? thanks
[image: NRF24L01 module]

Comment: This is not programmable in any language.  The computer you connect it to might be, but that's really not on topic here.  Only the necessary operations would be, and you can find those from the data sheet or numerous examples - though first you'd have to decide in which way you wanted to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the nRF24LO1 itself cannot be programmed. It can be used by other controllers, such as Arduino, RaspberryPi, or standalone AVR chips to communicate. Since you are asking for the Bascom Language, you will most likely use an AVR chip, ex. Atmega32.

There is a tutorial to using this module in Bascom at the official Bascom site, https://www.mcselec.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=212 .

There is also a datasheet available for this module, this can be found at https://www.google.ie/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjy7O95obWAhVMCMAKHR1vBMIQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sparkfun.com%2Fdatasheets%2FComponents%2FSMD%2FnRF24L01Pluss_Preliminary_Product_Specification_v1_0.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG9L4nJkLzsHDzTsCXNrA016LMA6Q .

I believe you would be best off using an Arduino to control the nRF24LO1, but Bascom can also achieve the same result. The language itself is easier to learn (it is a BASIC language), but there is more hardware knowledge involved. Specifically, to program standalone AVR chips you usually need an external programmer (with Bascom I used "KamPROG AVR", but you should be able to use any you have). Basically use your programmer to transfer the .hex file into the chip.

I can not really advise you further on this because I never used Bascom with nRF24LO1 personally, but this is a broad question and I just wanted to give you an overview on where you are going.

Comment: Many thanks my friend. I got it. I have written whole of my program but as the last part, I want to connect it to another circuit. Thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: No problem, just sharing experience. Good luck.